Language Selector component to re-route to correct Language page in NextJS with next-intl
I am struggling to get the re-routing right for language selection in my NextJS project. At the moment I have two languages EN (default) and PT.
The current behavior for the dev environment is:

Starting in localhost:3000 redirects to localhost:3000/en
Switching from EN -> PT, redirects to localhost:3000/pt but the text in the Dropdown is still EN
Clicking on PT again changes the value in the dropdown
Clicking on EN redirects to localhost:3000/en and changes the value in the dropdown
Clicking on PT redirects to localhost:3000/pt and keep the dropdown in EN

Desired behavior:

When first visiting localhost:3000 I want EN to be the default and to be displayed in the language selector
When switching to PT I want to be forwarded to localhost:3000/pt and the language selector should display PT
If switching back to EN then I should be re-routed to localhost:3000 or if clicking on the already selected PT language, nothing should happen
The same behavior should happen for all future added languages.
The rerouting should also work when more pages are added so for example from /en/about/something to /pt/about/something

Below is my middleware file and the LanguageSelect component. I am using next-intl package. Not sure if more information is required.

src/middleware.ts

import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { routing } from "./i18n/routing";

export default createMiddleware({
  locales: routing.locales,
  defaultLocale: routing.defaultLocale,
  localePrefix: "as-needed",
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)", "/(pt|en)/:path*"],
};



src/components/LanguageSelect.tsx

"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ChevronDown } from "lucide-react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dropdown-menu";
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "@/i18n/routing";
import { routing } from "@/i18n/routing";

export interface Language {
  code: (typeof routing.locales)[number];
  name: string;
}

export const languages: Language[] = routing.locales.map((locale) => ({
  code: locale,
  name: locale.toUpperCase(),
}));

interface LanguageSelectProps {
  isMobile: boolean;
}

export function LanguageSelect({ isMobile }: LanguageSelectProps) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState<Language>(
    languages[0]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const detectedLang =
      languages.find((lang) => pathname.startsWith(`/${lang.code}`)) ||
      languages.find((lang) => lang.code === routing.defaultLocale) ||
      languages[0];
    setCurrentLanguage(detectedLang);
  }, [pathname]);

  const handleLanguageChange = (lang: Language) => {
    setCurrentLanguage(lang);
    console.log(currentLanguage);
    router.push(pathname, { locale: lang.code });
  };

  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          className={`flex items-center space-x-1 bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-700 focus:ring-0 text-gray-200 ${
            isMobile ? "border border-gray-600" : ""
          }`}
        >
          <span>{currentLanguage.name}</span>
          <ChevronDown className="h-4 w-4" />
        </Button>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent className="bg-gray-800 border-gray-700">
        {languages.map((lang) => (
          <DropdownMenuItem
            key={lang.code}
            onClick={() => handleLanguageChange(lang)}
            className="hover:bg-gray-700 focus:bg-gray-700 text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-200 focus:text-gray-200"
          >
            {lang.name}
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}



Changing the import from:
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "@/i18n/routing";
To:
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
Solved everything. I have no idea why.

I did similar language based routing in my project and following was my approach. Try updating middleware as follows.
//middleware.tsx
const i18n = {
  locales: ["pt", "en"],
};
export default async function middleware(
  req: NextRequest,
  event: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  const localeInPathName = i18n.locales.find((locale) =>
    pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}`)
  );
  let locale = localeInPathName ?? "en";


  //for client routes only adding locale
  if (
    !localeInPathName &&
    !(
      pathname.startsWith("/_next") ||
      pathname.includes("/api/") ||
      PUBLIC_FILE.test(pathname)
    )
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/"}${pathname}`,
        req.url
      )
    );
  } 
//Other scenarios

}

Thanks for your answer but I don't think the rerouting should be happening on the middleware but on the component itself. I've updated the question because I got the rerouting to work but the display of the current language on the dropdown is very faulty still.
